# Is this instance created only once in my example?

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have the following code. In the other class, I tried to create the `S3ClientClass2` object as `val s3 = new S3ClientClass2()`. After creating the s3, then calling the `readFromS3` method for every single request.
In this scenario, I am wondering that the `amazonS3Client` is created only once or created many times for every request. I think that is is created only once.
Is this right?

```
class S3ClientClass2 {
  lazy val amazonS3Client = this.getS3Client()

  private def getS3Client() = {
    AmazonS3ClientBuilder
      .standard()
      .withRegion(Regions.AP_NORTHEAST_1)
      .build()
  }

  def readFromS3(s3Bucket: String, filepath: String): String = {
    var s3object: S3Object = null
    try {
      s3object = amazonS3Client.getObject(s3Bucket, filepath)
      readFromS3(s3object)
    }
    finally {
      if (s3object != null) {
        s3object.close()
      }
    }
  }

  def readFromS3(obj: S3Object): String = {
    val reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(obj.getObjectContent))
    reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining())
  }
}
```

Comment: Depends how many times you create a `S3ClientClass2` instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, `lazy val` is initialised only once when it is first used. That means, the first time you use `amazonS3Client` the `getS3Client` method will be called, every subsequent usage of `amazonS3Client` will use the cached value.

Some other hints. You are mixing in Java stuff in `readFromS3(obj: S3Object)` method for no good reason, it could be easily rewritten to pure Scala:

```scala
  def readFromS3(obj: S3Object): String = {
    scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(obj.getObjectContent).mkString
  }
```

Regarding `readFromS3(s3Bucket: String, filepath: String)`, you should never used `null` in scala, if you are working with something that might or might not have a value see `Option`, for things that might crash with some error see `scala.util.Either` and `scala.util.Try`. Also, what is the expected behaviour of this function when exception is thrown in the `try` block? In the current design it will rethrow it and escalate up your call stack.